# What is is_a in ruby and what does Integer mean?

Tags: ruby

What is `is_a` in ruby and what does Integer mean?

```
def prime(n)
  puts "That's not an integer." unless n.is_a? Integer
  is_prime = true
  for i in 2..n-1
    if n % i == 0
      is_prime = false
    end
  end
  if is_prime
    puts "#{n} is prime!"
  else
    puts "#{n} is not prime."
  end
end

prime(2)
prime(9)
prime(11)
prime(51)
prime(97)
```

Comment: You can't be bothered to google, huh?

Comment: -1. It's crazy question.

Answer (score 5):

[`Integer`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html) is class in a Ruby, which is the basis for the two concrete classes that hold whole numbers, Bignum and Fixnum.

[`Object#is_a?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F) method which *Returns true if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the superclasses of obj or modules included in obj.* Examples for the same :

```
irb(main):001:0> 5.class
=> Fixnum
irb(main):002:0> 5.is_a? Fixnum
=> true # because 5 is an instance of Fixnum
irb(main):003:0> 5.is_a? Integer
=> true # because Integer is a superclass of Fixnum, whose instance is 5 here.
irb(main):004:0> Fixnum.superclass
=> Integer
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

An integer is a whole number. Like- `1`, `4`, `5`, `2323`, `24284`, `5804508`.

A float is a number with decimal places. Like- `23.23`, `2323.232832`, `2323.239203`.

`n.is_a? Integer` is checking if the variable/parameter n is a integer or not.